# Dataview Xtemplate functions called twice while filter the store - ExtJS 4.1.1

Tags: extjs

I have problem with dataview store filter.

In tpl i have created the member function called 'isHeader' for grouping the header, If i'm having the multiple records under the same title. By default it is working good.

But when I'm searching the 'columnName', the header function called twice. So it always return false.

If the header function called once, it will return true. that time only i'm able to show header.

and please refer the JSON data and store & model.

```
{   
    "mainsummary": [
        {
            "Analysisoption": "Hosts Under Maintenance",
            "columnName": "java"
        },
        {
            "Analysisoption": "Hosts Under Maintenance",
            "columnName": "DC1"
        },
        {
            "Analysisoption": "Component Tests Maintenance",
            "columnName": "Java Classes",
            "hostName": "java:13600"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have declared the variable as global
`var titleObj = new Object();`

```
{
    xtype:'panel',
    tools:[
        {
             xtype: 'trigger',
             enableKeyEvents :true,
             scope: this,
             listeners : {
                specialkey: function(field, e){
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {                                        
                        srch = field.getValue();
                        var dataViewObj = Ext.getCmp('dataviewObj');
                        store = dataViewObj.getStore();
                        store.filterBy(function(record, id){
                            host = record.get('columnName');
                            pattern = new RegExp(srch, 'gi');
                            if((pattern.test(host))){
                                titleObj = new Object();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                        store.sort(); //important to maintain proper sort order in the list
                        Ext.getCmp('dataviewObj').refresh();
                    }
                },
             }                          
         }
    ],
    items: [{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        id:'dataviewObj',
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: [
                {name: 'columnName', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'hostName', type: 'string'},             
                {name: 'Analysisoption',  type: 'string'}
            ],
            data:mainsummary
        }),
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate([                                
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '{% var parentIndex = xindex; %}',
                '<div class="maintenanceTable"  style="margin:10px !important">',                                   
                        '<tpl if="!Ext.isEmpty(Analysisoption) && this.isHeader(Analysisoption)">',
                            '<div>{Analysisoption} </div>',
                        '</tpl>',
                        '<table id="tableId" border="0" align="center" width="100%">',
                            '<tbody>',
                                '<tr>',
                                    '<td><div>{columnName}</div></td>',
                                    '<tpl if="!Ext.isEmpty(hostName)">',
                                        '<td>{hostName}</td>',
                                    '</tpl>',
                                '</tr>',
                            '</tbody>',
                        '</table>',
                 '</div>',
             '</tpl>',
            {
                isHeader:function(Analysisoption){
                    console.log("isHeader",Analysisoption);
                    var isPrintHeader = false;
                    if(titleObj!=null && !titleObj.hasOwnProperty(Analysisoption))
                    {
                        titleObj[Analysisoption]=true;
                        isPrintHeader=true;                                     
                    }
                    return isPrintHeader;
                }
            }
        ])
    }]                  
}
```

Comment: isHeader will called once for every record that matched you filter. You didn't explain your problem clearly..

Comment: how do i group the analysisoption, while searching the columnName?It return matched records, But i didn't know the columnName belongs to which category(i.e) AnalysisOption.

Comment: can you reproduce this issue with [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?